# how would i insert a user's input into a Microsoft access through an Entry box

Tags: python, ms-access, tkinter, pyodbc

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sTkp.png)so I have successfully connected my Microsoft database to python and want to take the user's input through an entry box and insert the data into the database however I am struggling with doing so.

this is my code

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from re import S
import pyodbc
import random
w = tk.Tk()
char = "123456789ASDFGHJKLQWERTYUcharIOPZXCVBNMasdfghjklqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
try:
    con_string = r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\nekja\onedrive\Documents\teststing.accdb;'
    conn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
    print("Connected To Database")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    x = 0
    code = ""
    for i in range(0, 5):
        code_char = random.choice(char)
        code = code + code_char
    

    def new():
        name = name_box.get()
        print(name)

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        x = row[0]
    user_ID = x+1


    name_box = Entry(w,)
    name_box.grid(row=1, column=3)
    submit = Button(w, text="submit", command=new)
    submit.grid(row=1, column=5)

    myuser = (

        (user_ID, name, code),

    )

    cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?,?)', myuser)
    conn.commit()
    print('Data Inserted')


except pyodbc.Error as e:
    print("Error in Connection", e)


w.mainloop()
```

I tried to get the user's name through the entry box and when they click submit the name should be saved onto the database. however when retrieving the user's input I've had to create a new function called new  for the command in the submit button so the variable name in the tuple is no longer defined and not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

When you run into problems where you can't receive the output of a function, one option typically is to modify some mutable data type (either `list`, `dict` or by defining a `global` variable which in reality is modifying the mtuable `globals()` dict. This technique would look something like

```py
shared = {"name": None}
def new():
    shared["name"] = name_box.get()
```

However, in your particular case, accessing the input is not your only issue. You are using `tkinter` waiting for a user input, which forces you into asynchronous type code, and even with the example above, the `Entry` box will not get displayed until you call `w.mainloop()` at the end of your file.

Because of this, your best bet is not to think about how to get the `name` from the inner function to the outer function but more how can you get what you need from the outer function into the inner function. Something like this...

```py
def new():
    name = name_box.get()
    print(name)

    try:
        myuser = (

            (user_ID, name, code),

        )

        cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?,?)', myuser)
        conn.commit()
        print('Data Inserted')
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        print("Error in Connection", e)
```